# Acessar pasta datadir pela VM

Tags: php, mysql, vagrant, virtualbox

Meu cenário é o seguinte:

- /media/dados/svr/mysql
  Onde está localizado a minha pasta datadir do mysql.

O ambiente de desenvolvimento está rodando no vagrant (debian 6), com php 53 e mysql 5.5

Configurei a VM para acessar via NFS a pasta do datadir.
 O comando df -h  mostra isso:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/debian--607--x64--vbox4210-root
                      9.1G  1.4G  7.3G  16% /
tmpfs                 249M     0  249M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  244M  120K  244M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 249M     0  249M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             228M   16M  201M   8% /boot
192.168.53.1:/media/dados/svr/mysql
                       93G  4.7G   83G   6% /home/vagrant/servidor
/var/www               93G  9.4G   83G  11% /var/www
/vagrant              183G   56G  127G  31% /vagrant
/tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests
                      183G   56G  127G  31% /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests
```

A comando ls -al executado dentro do VM rodando no vagrant mostra a permissão da pasta assim:
drwxrwxr-x 6     115     125  4096 Apr 14 21:39 servidor/

Minha dúvida é como fazer para o mysql usar a pasta **/home/vagrant/servidor**?

No arquivo my.cnf já informei o caminho da datadir como
datadir = /home/vagrant/servidor - mas apresentou falha.

Quando informei:
datadir = 192.168.53.1:/media/dados/svr/mysql o sistema mostrou  a mensagem de erro  -

**/etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with

> 192.168.53.1:/media/dados/svr/mysql is too full! ... failed!

Como fazer para a máquina virtual enteder que a pasta datadir do mysql está na unidade /dados/svr/mysql montado via nfs?

Comment: Você consegue acessar os logs ? Talvez indique mais alguma coisa nos logs que ajude a identificar o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quem estiver interessado, consegui resolver o problema do compartilhamento e acesso da seguinte forma:

No arquivo Vagrantfile gerado pelo PuPHPET, adicionei o **owner e group** no momento em que ele monta a pasta. Dizendo que o dono da pasta será o mysql e o grupo mysql.

```
data['vm']['synced_folder'].each do |i, folder|
    if folder['source'] != '' && folder['target'] != '' && folder['id'] != ''
      nfs = (folder['nfs'] == "true") ? "nfs" : nil
      config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", id: "#{folder['id']}", **owner: "mysql", group: "mysql",** type: nfs
    end
  end
```

No arquivo config.yaml, criei o compartilhamento conforme abaixo.

```
 synced_folder:
            0C0LWqoKUqOI:
                source: /media/dados/svr/mysql
                target: /home/vagrant/servidor
                nfs: 'false'
```

Para finalizar após parar o mysql na máquina virtual , alterei o caminho do datadir de var/lib/mysql para  **/home/vagrant/servidor**

A partir disso inicializei o mysql e funcionou.